# Start Activity only if called by NFC

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

I have activity A that is the MAIN and activity B that is another activity that i use for the app. Now, i want to execute the app B only if is called by NFC tag.

I wrote an NFC tag that runs the app com.test.nfc)" (that is the package of my test app). It works, but it runs the MAIN (activity A) of course, and is not what i want.

If i use NFC i want that the main app will be the Activity B (i repeat, only if i run the app with NFC). Is there any way?

I tried to launch the activity using the Tasker app from PlayStore, but it works only if this app is installed, if i uninstall it, it not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the intent-filter for the activity you want to run only on NFC then on your manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.activity.a"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.activity.b"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="ext"
                android:pathPrefix="/com.example:ddcnfc"
                android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the above example, activty A runs from Launcher, activty B from NFC.

Then in the onResume function of activty B class,

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        //Your initialization goes here
    }
}
```